# Sending a confirmation email with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I am attempting to send a confirmation email to a newly registered user using Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0.0.

I am not getting any errors but the mail just is not sending.  Here is the relevant code:

config/environments/development.rb

```
...
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :authenication=>:plain,
    :address=>"smpt.mailgun.org",
    :port=>587,
    :domain=>"sandboxf4f4c96ebc7b4eb1b6c7475ad4de048c.mailgun.org",
    :user_name=>"postmaster@sandboxf4f4c96ebc7b4eb1b6c7475ad4de048c.mailgun.org",
    :password=>"6j3c9l35tu33"
  }
```

app/model/user.rb

```
...
  def create
    @user=User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      ModelMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver
        redirect_to lessons_url
    else
        render :new
    end
  end
```

mailers/model_mailer.rb

```
class ModelMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me@sandboxf4f4c96ebc7b4eb1b6c7475ad4de048c.mailgun.org"

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user

    mail to: "myemail@gmail.com", subject: "Account Activation"
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try changing port no if above answer is not sufficient

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: did you change config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true, as by default this is on false, preventing mails to be sent from your development environment...